# What subset of functional programming aspects and Lisp-like features does JavaScript provide?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lisp

Right to the point, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696618/is-haskell-a-lisp?answertab=votes#tab-top, there is a comment by Kevin Cantu saying:

> Yeah, moving beyond the syntax alone, JavaScript is probably more of
>   a Lisp than Haskell. (Originally conceived as a Scheme
>   implementation...)

Also, in [Lambda the Ultimate: A Lisp to JavaScript Compiler in 100 Lines](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/892), they say:

> It's immediately quite clear that JS and Lisp have strong ties at the
>   semantics level [...]

I am familiar with Lisp and functional programming, but not with JavaScript. So these propositions made wonder how powerful is JavaScript. What I've read so far is that it provides lambda expressions and closures. What more functional programming concepts and Lisp-like features does it provide? Does it provide, for instance, tail call recursion, or macros, or ability to manipulate code as data (like Lisp)?

Comment: JavaScript is a full-featured OO language, not an ad-hoc HTML helper. But is this really the right forum to discuss it?

Comment: I am *not* aiming for a subjective discussion about whether JavaScript is ad-hoc or not. I am sorry if I gave that impression. My question is simply about which functional features it has.

Comment: No macros, no tail-call optimization (for now).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some things that JavaScript provides that can be considered "Lisp-like":

- First class functions (inc. lambdas and closures)
- Dynamic typing
- Dynamic object model that has some similarities with [CLOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System)
- A readable data format that matches the source code format (JSON)
- Run time evaluation with an "eval" function (that can be used in an interactive [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop))

Some things that Javascript doesn't have that are pretty common or central to other Lisps:

- A homoiconic representation for both code and data (S-expressions)
- Built in literals for linked lists / sequences
- Support for immutable data structures in general (especially true for Clojure, where *every* data structure is [persistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) and immutable)
- An extensive macro system for meta-programming
- Optional static typing for performance optimisation (e.g. type hints in Common Lisp or Clojure)
- Concurrency support
- Tail call optimisation

Comment: Another feature that's paramount to Lisps and functional programming languages that Javascript does not have is a built-in type and literal syntax for linked lists. And good support for immutable data structures in general. Another feature common in functional programming languages (though not in Common Lisp) that javascript is missing is tail-call optimization.

Comment: And with *eval* we can also build a LISP like REPL which all the nice Javascript debuggers now have.