# is Haskell a lisp dialect

Tags: haskell, lisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Haskell a Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696618/is-haskell-a-lisp)

Many people who have worked on Lisp told me that Haskell is one of the dialects of Lisp. I searched on internet but could not find the proper answer. Can somebody explain regarding this?

Comment: Ask one of those who told you for a reference

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696618/is-haskell-a-lisp provides a reference: it says that The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming by Doets and Eijck 2004 makes this claim.

Answer (score 5):

No, it isn't. See: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/History_of_Haskell

Answer (score 3):

They're playfully referring to rich metaprogramming and multi-paradigm capabilities of Lisp which allow using various programming styles, which may also lead to thinking of all other languages as merely particular cases of Lisp. Some implementations of Lisp family languages, like [Racket](http://racket-lang.org) implementation of Scheme, contain features also seen in Haskell, like static types, pattern matching or lazy evaluation.

And remember that

> Whoever does not understand LISP, is doomed to reinvent it